# PythonWin won't import simple script

Tags: python

I am unable to run the following simple script into PythonWin (pywin32-227.win32-py3.8.exe
 at [this link](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases)).

```
# Test.py

print("test565")
```

I haven't been able to make heads or tails of the error that results when I hit Ctrl-I:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\blorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\intpyapp.py", line 330, in OnFileImport
    scriptutils.ImportFile()
  File "C:\Users\blorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 403, in ImportFile
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
  File "C:\Users\blorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 204, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\blorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\intpyapp.py", line 330, in OnFileImport
    scriptutils.ImportFile()
  File "C:\Users\blorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 403, in ImportFile
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
  File "C:\Users\blorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 204, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\blorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\intpyapp.py", line 330, in OnFileImport
    scriptutils.ImportFile()
  File "C:\Users\blorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 403, in ImportFile
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
  File "C:\Users\blorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 204, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

The same script runs fine from the Windows command prompt, e.g.

```
C:\Users\blorp\Documents\Research\VMs\Jack>python -m Test
test565
```

Any clue where to start with this? We've re-installed both Python 3.8 and PythonWin.

Comment: Any additional codes you have, where is the import of the library?

Comment: There aren't any module imports in the code. It's just the three-line script above, with only one actual line in it. When I said I couldn't import the script, I meant that hitting Ctrl-I in PythonWin resulted in the error seen above. I will clarify in the post.

Comment: What is Ctrl+l supposed to do in PythonWin?

Comment: Ctrl-I is import/reload from the script editing window.